# In c# is there an easy way to test if a value is in an inline-coded set?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, set

In C# if I want to see if a variable is equal to one of a set of fixed values, I currently do this...

```
bool result = ( (x==MyEnum.A) || (x==MyEnum.B) || (x==42) );
```

...which to me is cumbersome.  Is there anything similar to this pseudo-code?

```
bool result = x in {MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, 42};
```

I know I can create an array inline with the values, then use LINQ across that, but are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a BAD idea, but you can turn Contains on its head and get syntax similar to what you ask in your question with a new extension method:

```
//Generic.  All items in the set and the candidate must be the same type.
public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T [] set)
{
  return set.Contains(item);
}

bool result = x.In(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C);

//Non-generic and non-typesafe.  Anything goes.  Use with care!
public static bool In(this object item, params object [] set)
{
  return set.Contains(item);
}


bool result = x.In(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, 42);

//int-specific.  
public static bool In(this int item, params int [] set)
{
  return set.Contains(item);
}


bool result = x.In((int)MyEnum.A, (int)MyEnum.B, 42);
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm missing something here, but you declared your extension method `In` as a generic, yet when you used it, you didn't specify the type.  Does that syntax automatically assume 'T' is the type you attach it to (in this case the type of 'x')?

Comment: Yes.  If you want to pass in mixed types, such as in your example, you could make the signature non-generic and take object as the parameter.  Or if you intend to use it with enums and ints, again, as in your example, you could declare the type to be int and cast your enums to ints when you make the call.

Comment: Actually, I just tried this and it worked! :)  I never knew a generic assumed what it was attached to and therefore your `In` statement now works for all types.  Pretty damn sweet!  Gives me what I want (inline) and taught me something new about C# generics as a bonus! We have a winnarrrr!

Comment: FYI, we added this to the System.Linq namespace so whenever we add a using for that, we automatically get this too.  Again, pretty damn sweet!

Comment: @MarqueIV: FYI That's called generic inference.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ, you can reverse this (test if `x` is in a list) by using [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357185.aspx):

```
var myList = new[] {MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, (MyEnum)42};
result = myList.Contains(x);
```

Comment: Does this compile for you?  I get 'error CS0820: Cannot initialize an implicitly-typed local variable with an array initializer'

Comment: It is faulty, you have either to cast the int to enum or enum to int, another error is the lack of new[] before the set

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new[] { (int)MyEnum.A, (int)MyEnum.B, 42 }.Contains(x);
```

or even better:

Create extension method:

```
    public static bool ContainedIn(this MyEnum input, params MyEnum[] parameters)
    {
        return parameters.Contains(input); 
    }
```

`var result = x.ContainedIn(MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B)`;

and if you want to allow multiple types you can use object as the params type

Comment: Voting you up because this is similar to the answer I accepted: the difference being that in his case, he used a generic on the extension method so we can use it with everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the Enumerable.Contains() extension method, which is available for all IEnumerable types:

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value);
```

The syntax is still a little ugly, but you can get close to what you want:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A, B, C
}
public static void Test()
{
    MyEnum x = MyEnum.C;
    bool result = new[] { MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, (MyEnum)42 }.Contains(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is too long but values you look for is ordered in your enum definition, you can create  a range and call Contains() on it like this:

```
bool result = Enumerable.Range((int)MyEnum.First,(int)MyEnum.Last)
                        .Contains((int)x);
```

This will come in handy on conditions above but I wanted to post this because you did not want to create an inline array.